# Dual Gang Shallow / Half depth electrical box

Tags: electrical, receptacle, shallow

I have a wall and on one side is a switch for the lights, on the other I want to install a switch for lights and a fan. I need a shallow depth electrical box for both sides - any one know if these are made in PVC / Plastic and where to get  / who manufactures?

Is it with in code to do this , or just rare that we can't find them?

Comment: Likely to run afoul of box fill calculations unless you get a larger shallow box and use a cover that reduces to the gangs you require. A shallow gang box has extremely limited volume. A 4x4x1.5 or 4-11/16x4-11/16x1.5 with appropriate cover has the space you'll likely need. In steel. Not sure what you can or can't find in plastic, nor do I recommend using plastic boxes.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean US, as no country was mentioned - but if anyone finds this question looking for UK boxes, standard depths are 25, 35 & 47 mm - https://www.screwfix.com/c/electrical-lighting/back-boxes/cat7230011?numberofgangs=2_gang#category=cat7230011&numberofgangs=2_gang&parentcolour=steel You can also get plastic for drywall - https://www.screwfix.com/c/electrical-lighting/back-boxes/cat7230011?numberofgangs=2_gang#category=cat7230011&backboxtype=dry_lining&numberofgangs=2_gang

Comment: Is there a reason the two boxes must be directly across from one another?

Comment: Offset the boxes by a few inches.

Comment: Why do you need it to be plastic?

Comment: Is this for interior walls in a home? It can’t be on a firewall back to back would be a code violation in a fire wall.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - yes there is a reason - the placement of the unit on the one wall - if I move it interfere with other things on that wall and further aesthetically would not match anything else in the room. On the other side placement would be bad if elsewhere - where it is now is really bad. While it works it is very bad placement.

Comment: @EdBeal Interior to interior - think Toilet room Water Closet , and the rest of the en-suite.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Everything in the home is plastic already, a plastic box is already a natural insulator. no need to add another wire - although if metal is the only option - I get no real choice ..

Comment: Not "everything". I'm sure your main panel is metal. But seriously, you can have a metal box even if most of the other boxes are plastic. Metal boxes are perfectly compatible with NM cable (on the other hand, plastic boxes don't work so well with metal conduit). Yes, plastic is a natural insulator, but the metal of a metal box is grounded, so it doesn't *need* insulation - it is effectively the same as a metal appliance case (washer, dryer, oven, water heater, etc.) (with the exception of old 3-wire dryers/etc. but that is a different issue).

Comment: @ + true and for those that have seen electrical fires in boxes with metal the fire stops there, some of the plastic melt and make a mess but usually put the fire out, but a fire in the room and all the plastic boxes may melt, my first small home fire I was surprised that several boxes melted quite a way from the actual fire, what a mess.

Answer (score 4):

It's super easy with metal boxes.

- Two 4 x 4 x 1-1/2" metal box with knockouts, generic 99 cent variety (unless you want [ones with nailing strips](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RACO-2-Gang-Electrical-Square-Box-8196/100551666))
- One [box spacer connector](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-1-2-in-Rigid-Box-Spacer-91641/100144864) (or 2 for extra stability)
- [NM (Romex) cable clamp connectors](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-Non-Metallic-NM-Twin-Screw-Cable-Clamp-Connectors-5-Pack-20511/100133208?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-100197570-_-100133208-_-N) (to guide it into a knockout)

Knock out a KO on the back of the 2 boxes (so they line up) and connect them back2back with the box spacer connector.  Mount on the walls.

Follow with

- two 1-gang or 2-gang ["mud rings"](https://www.homedepot.com/s/mud%2520ring?NCNI-5) the height of your drywall.

Easy peasy.  About 26 square inches between box and mud ring. More room than a plastic box.

Before you complain about the bill of materials, it uses less wire. Interconnects between boxes are handled by passing through the hole in the spacer connector, so a short pigtail will suffice.  Ground is handled by the metal boxes and connector(s), just ground the incoming cables to the box they enter.

Of course that involves using metal boxes, and we can't have that. *Wait, why can't we have that?  We uses boxes for reasons, and metal is superior at every single reason*.  Plastic is used because it's cheap, but only for people who buy pallet quantity - Home Depot does not pass those savings onto you. If you're thinking "boxes that insulate are better", no, electrical safety is optimized for the exact oppsoite - you want a loose wire to be instantly grounded and trip the breaker.

Mud rings are a little weird to get used to, I'll give you that.

Comment: I am thinking I have no choice, I like those plastic smart boxes because I can screw them in place; remove the old and in with the new and minimal invasive-ness (next to nothing). With nailer's - I need to cut open the dry wall quite a bit. Alas it looks like I don't have much choice. Agree - ground a hot and tripping the breaker is better than a loose wire.

Comment: Metal boxes can be screwed into place. In fact, they handle moving around, reattaching, etc. much better than plastic.

Comment: @Ken that is an issue; a 4x4 box needs a bigger hole than a standard 1-gang opening, and trying to assemble 2 boxes with a coupler *in the wall* would suck.  But FWIW, my usual box doesn't have nailer wings, I just drill extra holes in the box  *not on knockouts* and screw them into the stud. Metal boxes are strong enough for improvised mounting methods.  (Torx deck screws with a 90 degree ratchet screwdriver, I love that tool).